# 7,7-dichlorobicyclo[4.1.0]heptane NMR solving

Tags: organic-chemistry, nmr-spectroscopy

i made a synthesis of this material in the lab and now i got the H-NMR specta , and by litreture i know that i got the right product.
im having trouble to match the hydrogens to the peaks,i tried to look at the molecule in it chair form, i know that the 2 hydrogens(A) attached to the cl cl group are in the highest ppm than the other 4 (B), but on the last 4 i got 2 different multiplets, which is a match to which hydrogens? i added the  spectrum
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would start by looking at the cis rather than trans isomer as the starting point for interpreting the NMR spectrum. It is much more likely to be the product you got from this reaction. Also, be sure to identify all the chemically distinct hydrogens in your structures.